# React + immutable.js: merge Map into List of Maps to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, immutable.js

I'm trying out immutable.js in my new React project, but I'm having a blackout at adding a Map to an existing List of Maps in my state.

I would previously have written (using Arrays and Objects):

```
this.setState({
  objectsArray: [...this.state.objectsArray, newObject];
})
```

But I'm struggling to find the proper equivalent with immutable.js. I've tried things along the lines of this, but with no success:

`state.get('mapsList').merge(newMap);`

I'm finding plenty of examples on the web merging Lists and merging Maps, but I'm having a List of Maps, and the official docs on immutable Lists are not exactly elaborate.

Links to resources and best practices regarding React/Redux state operations appreciated as well, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "old" code creates a new array with the same objects that already existed, plus a new object.

As far as I can see, Immutable's [`List#push`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/push) does the same thing:

> **`push()`**
>
> Returns a new `List` with the provided `values` appended, starting at this `List`'s `size`.
>
> ```
> push(...values: Array<T>): List<T>
> ```

So:

```
this.setState(({mapsList}) => {
    return {mapsList: mapsList.push(newMap)};
});
```

---

Side note: I'm using the callback version of `setState` because you're not allowed to do what your old code did. If you're setting new state based on existing state, you **must** use the callback; [details](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Comment: Hi T.J., thank you, this is what i was looking for. Also thanks for calling me out on not using the callback on setState. :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to update the list with

`state = state.updateIn(['mapsList'], function(list) { return list.push(newMap); })`

that will update the mapsList List with the new newMap

Comment: I'm assuming `this.state` is the standard React state object, which is just a boring old object. Are you assuming the OP is doing something else, using some Immutable class instead?

Comment: Re your edit: *`state = state.updateIn(...)`* You can't do that in react. You're not assign to directly assign to `state` (nor to directly modify any of its properties, or their properties).

Comment: is not completely clear in the question, I understood it was changing an immutable state

Comment: `this.setState` and `this.state` make it fairly clear in a React context.

Comment: because he talks about redux, so I assumed it was the state as immutable (or redux)

Comment: Even so, you can't directly assign to `this.state` with React+Redux, can you?

Comment: 'state' is the state from redux, is not the `this.state` from React... is the actual state of a Store

Comment: Okay, I'm going to assume it makes sense in a ReactJS+Redux context, that's not an area I know much about. :-)

Comment: yes, my second code snippet was actually from a Redux context, while the first on wasn't. sorry for the confusion. And thank you as well UXDart for the 'updateIn' example.